# When to use the "await" keyword

Tags: c#, web-services, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm writing a web page, and it calls some web services. The calls looked like this:

```
var Data1 = await WebService1.Call();
var Data2 = await WebService2.Call();
var Data3 = await WebService3.Call();
```

During code review, somebody said that I should change it to:

```
var Task1 = WebService1.Call();
var Task2 = WebService2.Call();
var Task3 = WebService3.Call();

var Data1 = await Task1;
var Data2 = await Task2;
var Data3 = await Task3;
```

Why? What's the difference?

Comment: Unless it's some sort of copy issue, I don't see any reason a decent compiler wouldn't optimize out the extra assignment. I don't know enough about C# to say for sure though. Perhaps it's just a semantic issue, and your team prefers to make it explicit that the call is a task while the result of the task is data?

Comment: @JAB That's not true.  There's a *dramatic* difference in the semantic meaning of these two code snippets.

Comment: @servy what is your semantic for semantic ?

Comment: @Servy I stand corrected. As I don't use C# much, I was under the impression that `await` is used to allow non-blocking variable assignment for asynchronous methods when it's actually the opposite.

Comment: @JAB Can you think of something better?  (Not that it could really be changed at this point anyway.)   A lot of people spent a lot of time thinking about what would be appropriate.

Comment: @JAB `await` effectively means, "evaluate the following expression to a task (generally starting it), add a continuation to that task in which it will continue executing the current method where it left off,  then the execution in the current context stops.  You can think of it as an asynchronous wait if you want, but that's a very leaky abstraction to work with.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't supposed to be a proper answer, that's why I posted it as a comment. Regarding my other comment, though, are there languages that do support non-blocking/asynchronous object assignments (or rather, implicit synchronization), such that you could do something like `var Data1 = await Task1; var Data2 = await Task2;`, and then `var Data3 = operationOn(Data1, Data2); doSomethingElseWhileWeWait();`, and the last method would execute immediately as long as it has no dependencies on Data3, Data2, or Data1...

Comment: ...while the assignment to `Data3` would complete as soon as the assignments to `Data1` and `Data2` complete? (Essentially, each assignment would become its own thread, and the code would build up a continuation graph [not sure if that's the best way to describe it] from each assignment thread to the next dependent ones.)

Comment: @JAB And you would model that, in C#, by having each of the data variables be `Task` types, not the actual underlying types, and having all of the functions acting on them accepting tasks and not blocking.

Comment: Well that makes sense.

Comment: @Eric You should post a new question for your new question, not edit your existing one. However it is the same as your posted code except your results are stored in an array instead of 3 variables.

Comment: @Servy Looks like I was thinking of promise pipelining: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises#Promise_pipelining

Comment: @JAB A `Task` is essentially a promise/future, more or less.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the first code snippet you're not even *starting* the second service call until the first service call completes (and likewise not starting the third until the second completes).  In short, they are executed sequentially.

In the second snippet you start all three service calls, but then don't continue on in the code until all three are done.  In short, they are all executed in parallel.

If the second/third calls are unable to be *started* until they have the result of the previous operation then you would need to do something like the first snippet in order to make it work.  If the service calls don't depend on each other at all then you'd want them to be executed in parallel for performance reasons.

If, for some reason, you really dislike having the extra local variables, there are other ways of executing the tasks in parallel using alternate syntaxes.  One alternative that would act like your second option is:

```
var Data = await Task.WhenAll(WebService1.Call(), 
    WebService2.Call(), 
    WebService3.Call());
```

Comment: Doesn't the code stop at await Task1 until Task1 is done, then stop at Task2 and wait for Task2, etc?

Comment: The thread with `await` will stop, but the two tasks would continue making progress.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah, I was already in the process of editing that in when you commented.  Seems I manged to ninja it in there before 5 min. ;)

Comment: @EricB Which snippet are you referring to?  Also keep in mind that `await` doesn't mean *wait*.  It's not blocking the thread.  The first snippet starts the second task in the continuation of the first task, then starts the third in the continuation of the second.  The other snippet starts all three at once, then does stuff after the continuations of all three have run.

Comment: @StephenCleary So, Task.WhenAll(...) Is *not* the same as 3 awaits?

Comment: @EricB As per my answer, using `WhenAll` will be functionally equivalent to the second snippet.  It is *not* equivalent to the first snippet.

Comment: @EricB: `WhenAll` would be more efficient, and personally I think it captures the desired semantics better ("await for all these to complete" instead of "await the first one, then the second, then the third").

Answer (score 38):

Servy's answer is correct; to expand on that a little. What's the difference between:

```
Eat(await cook.MakeSaladAsync());
Eat(await cook.MakeSoupAsync());
Eat(await cook.MakeSandwichAsync());
```

and

```
Task<Salad> t1 = cook.MakeSaladAsync();
Task<Soup> t2 = cook.MakeSoupAsync();
Task<Sandwich> t3 = cook.MakeSandwichAsync();
Eat(await t1);
Eat(await t2);
Eat(await t3);
```

?

The first is:

- Cook, please make me a salad
- While waiting for the salad, you have some free time to brush the cat. When you're done that, oh, look, the salad is done.  **If the cook finished the salad while you were brushing the cat, they did not start on making the soup because you haven't asked for it yet**.
- Eat the salad.  **The cook is now idle while you eat.**
- Cook, please make me some soup.
- While waiting for the soup you have some free time to clean the fish tank. When you're done that, oh, look, the soup is done. **If the cook finishes the soup while you are cleaning the fish tank, they do not start on the sandwich because you haven't asked for it yet.**
- Eat the soup. **The cook is now idle while you eat.**
- Cook, please make me a sandwich.
- Again, find something else to do while you're waiting.
- Eat the sandwich.

Your second program is equivalent to:

- Cook, please make me a salad
- Cook, please make me some soup.
- Cook, please make me a sandwich.
- Is the salad done? If not, while waiting for the salad, you have some free time to brush the cat. **If the cook finished the salad while you were brushing the cat, they started making the soup**.
- Eat the salad.  **The cook can still be working on the soup and sandwich while you are eating.**
- Is the soup done? ...

You see the difference? In your original program you don't tell the cook to start the next course until you are done *eating* the first course. In your second program you request all three courses up front, and eat them -- in order -- as they come available.  The second program makes better use of the cook's time because the cook can "get ahead" of you.

Comment: I think it's important to note that the cook can make multiple dishes simultaneously, which doesn't seem to be explicitly stated. So in case 2 when you ask for all 3 dishes the cook may be capable of making the salad while the soup is worming up on the oven. which is why in case 1 it doesn't make sense to ask the cook to make one thing at a time since they can make more than one dish at a time.

Comment: @Letseatlunch: That's a good point but it is not necessary for my argument; the relevant point here is that when you ask for all three things first, the service provider can do them all at once, or one after the other, but at least they know *to do all three*.  If you don't ask for the second until the first is done then you're possibly underutilizing a resource.

Answer (score 1):

[Servy posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844150/80274) a very good answer, but here is a visual description using `Task`s to help show what the problem is. This code will not be functionaly the same as yours (it does not do all the synchronization context stuff like giving back control to the message pump) but it illustrates the problem very well.

Your code is doing something like this

```
var fooTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo);
fooTask.Wait();
var fooResult = fooTask.Result;

var barTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Bar);
barTask.Wait();
var barResult = barTask.Result;

var bazTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Baz);
bazTask.Wait();
var bazResult = bazTask.Result;
```

and the corrected code is doing something like this

```
var fooTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo);
var barTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Bar);
var bazTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Baz);

fooTask.Wait();
var fooResult = fooTask.Result;
barTask.Wait();
var barResult = barTask.Result;
bazTask.Wait();
var bazResult = bazTask.Result;
```

You can see that all 3 tasks are running while waiting for the first result to get back, where in the first example the 2nd task does not start until the first task is finished.